# Qt 6: Trouble parsing Json, object within an object

Tags: c++, json, api, qt

im am trying to create a mashup c++ application that makes a request to an API that gives me a Json and parse information from it. The API I am using is from tv maze (https://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=) where the name of the tv show goes after the "=" sign and it returns a list of shows.

I am trying to make it where this application will let me search the tv show and return the name of the show, rating, and image of the show, and if there's multiple results it will display them as well.

I have gotten the the json to display in my code but I am having trouble trying to parse the Json.

In my code below I am trying to get the value from "name" in https://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=arcane so I can store the value of the name of the show but with my code below it just returns an empty string.

Am I misunderstanding something? Is the problem in the way my Json is being read in? this is my first time attempting to use APIs and working with Jsons. Thank you!

`

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);

    QString url = "https://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=" + show_in;
    QNetworkRequest request(url);

        connect(manager,SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
               this,SLOT(managerFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
        manager->get(request);    // The get request is made here
}

void MainWindow::managerFinished(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
    QByteArray *myByteArray = new QByteArray();
    myByteArray->append(reply->readAll());
    QJsonDocument myJson = QJsonDocument::fromJson(*myByteArray);
    qDebug() << myJson;

    // Now we parse the json data


    QJsonObject myObj = myJson.object();
    QJsonValue myValue = myObj.value("show");
    QJsonObject nshow = myValue.toObject();
    QJsonValue val1 = nshow.value("name");
    QString nameS = val1.toString();
    qDebug() << "show: " << nameS;


}



MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

`

Comment: The result is an array, not an object.

Comment: So the problem is how im reading the Json in? or how its outputted?

Comment: Just convert myJson to array, then take the first item, it will be your myObj. You should verify if the array is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

API returns an array, not an object. The documentation of `QJsonDocument::object()` says:

> Returns an empty object if the document contains an array.

So you should call `QJsonDocument::array()` and after it you can iterate it:

```
for (const auto& item : myJson.array())  {
    QJsonObject myObj = item .toObject();
    QJsonValue myValue = myObj.value("show");
    QJsonObject nshow = myValue.toObject();
    QJsonValue val1 = nshow.value("name");
    QString nameS = val1.toString();
    qDebug() << "show: " << nameS;
}
```

* I wrote the code not in the IDE, so you might have to fix it. But I suppose you got the idea.